# Pass potentially infinite number of arguments to array except a single numeric variable in a PHP command line script

Tags: php, windows, linux, command-line, arguments

I'm trying to make a PHP script that will take a potentially infinite number of URLs from the command line as arguments. I also need to pass an argument that only has a single numeric value possible (to specify timeout), e.g.:

```
./urltest.php 60 url1.com url2.com url3.com
```

I'm not exactly sure how to specify argv[1] to be a single numeric variable while at the same time the rest of the arguments (i.e. the list of urls) go into an array. Maybe something like:

```
$timeout = $argv[1];
$args = func_get_args();    

function numfilter($num) {
    return !is_numeric($num);
}

$urls = array_filters($args, 'numfilter');
```

?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I actually wrote a small PHP library for handling these types of things. You can find it on GitHub [here](https://github.com/jordanhalterman/ParParse). I've used it for a while and have found it to be very useful for this type of thing, I just never put in any real effort to tell anyone else about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you want `func_get_args`.  That's for getting all the arguments for the current function.  It has nothing to do with the command line.  I'd do it something like

```
//i don't like altering the global $argv
$urls    = $argv;

//take off the first element of the array, leaving only urls
$script = array_shift($argv); //shift off script name, per other post :)
$timeout = array_shift($urls); 
if(!is_numeric($timeout)) exit ("First argument was not a number") //array_shift always makes me break out perl style, so this however you want
//your $urls variable now contains an array with arguments 2 - n
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to make two calls to array_shift, since argv[0] will be the name of the script.